# Consulta en mysql lenta

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo esta consulta en mysql:

```
SELECT MIN(`Dc3`) +1 as prox_ean_libre FROM (SELECT `Dc3` FROM `Test` WHERE `Dc3` BETWEEN '".$Eanmin."' AND '".$Eanmax."') t1 WHERE not exists (select null FROM `Test` t2 WHERE t2.`Dc3` = t1.`Dc3` + 1 AND t2.`Dc3` BETWEEN '".$Eanmin."' AND '".$Eanmax."'
```

En ella busco el primer código libre que hay entre dos números. el caso es que funciona pero es extremadamente lenta cuando mysql tiene muchos registros. ¿hay alguna forma de hacer que sea mas rápida?

Eanmin es 8434452000001 y Eanmax 8434452099999 
Dc3 es un campo varchar 200

Comment: SELECT MIN(`Dc3`) +1 as prox_ean_libre 
FROM `Test` t1 WHERE t1.`Dc3` BETWEEN '".$Eanmin."' AND '".$Eanmax."'
   and not in(select Dc3 from Test t2 WHERE t2.`Dc3` = t1.`Dc3` + 1 AND t2.`Dc3` BETWEEN '".$Eanmin."' AND '".$Eanmax."')

Comment: De por sí, por diseño, tu consulta no va a ser muy rápida.  Pero si no has definido un índice en la columna `Dc3`, va a ser **extremadamente** lento. ¿Has definido un índice en esa columna?

Answer (score 1):

Estás usando dos subqueries cuando podrías usar una sola query

```
SELECT MIN(`Dc3`)+1 as prox_ean_libre
FROM `Test` t1
LEFT JOIN `Test` t2 ON t2.`Dc3`=(t1.`Dc3`)+1 AND t2.`Dc3` BETWEEN '".$Eanmin."' AND '".$Eanmax."'
WHERE t1.`Dc3`BETWEEN '".$Eanmin."' AND '".$Eanmax."'
AND t2.`Dc3` IS NULL
```

Entre paréntesis, tu query está interpolando el valor de las variables en la misma sentencia. Sin más contexto no sé cómo recomendarte cambiarla, pero debieras usar placeholders para las variables `$Eanmin` y `$Eanmax` para dejar, por ejemplo (en PDO)

```
$sql = "SELECT MIN(`Dc3`)+1 as prox_ean_libre
    FROM `Test` t1
    LEFT JOIN `Test` t2 ON t2.`Dc3`=(t1.`Dc3`)+1 AND t2.`Dc3` BETWEEN :eanmin AND :eanmax
    WHERE t1.`Dc3`BETWEEN :eanmin AND :eanmax
    AND t2.`Dc3` IS NULL";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([
  ':eanmin' => $Eanmin,
  ':eanmax' => $Eanmax
]);
```

**PS1**: supongo que tienes un índice en Dc3

Comment: para que sirven los indices exactamente?

Comment: Perfecto, he puesto el indice en dc3 y puesta tu consulta y ahora ya responde bien :) muchas gracias.

Comment: usando la consulta tal cual la pones dice que dc3 es ambigua ¿que puede ser?

Comment: creo que ya lo tengo he puesto SELECT MIN(t1.`Dc3`)+1 as prox_ean_libre.... y ya se ejecuta :) ¿esta bien o eso estaría mal?